# Android firebase and google integration

Tags: android, firebase, google-plus

services.json file . First I download it for google integration and second is for firebase integration. Now I'm confused to use which one. Both are having different client ids.How can have single google-services.json and use it for both firebase and google integration?

Comment: Are they in different projects in the google API console? By default Firebase will generate a new project and you might be adding Google APIs to a different project. Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) and check if your Firebase project is separate from your "Google" project.

Comment: No I'm having both for same project. First I made google integration that was before 4 months now i have to integrate fcm too. I dont know what to replace. Actually developer console is maintained by my client and he is not ready to give me information.

Comment: Try taking a look at their official documentation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826377/firebase-google-auth-sign-is-getting-failed/40826403#40826403

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend, if you have access to the Google project but not the developer's console, is to access the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), click "Import Google Project", and select your existing project.

This will create a new Firebase project that integrates with your existing Google project, in theory allowing you to use the same API keys, and by extension, the same "google-services.json" file.

Comment: Do you mean to click Import Google Project from google console or in firebase console.

Comment: @user6444945 It's right next to the "Create new project" button in the Firebase Console.