# Firebase google auth sign is getting failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to do Firebasegoogle authentication, but everytime am getting

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
```

`task.isSuccessful()` as false with the follwing exception

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I added my SHA1 key to Firebaseconsole properly and google-services.json to my app folder. Please let me know if anything else is going wrong

My Project gradle inclucdes:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

App gradle includes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
```

With following configuration:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: please post snippets of your code , app gradle and project gradle as well .

Comment: updated the gradles, remaining code I have taken from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L80-L84